# My do while loop is running once more than it should (I think)

Tags: c#, database, loops, do-while

this is a database program and by entering a number 0-7 you can do different things with the data files. Whenever I try to quit by entering a 0 it sends me through the loop again and then once I put in another 0 it will quit.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            do
            {
                DoAQuery();
                Console.WriteLine();


            } while (DoAQuery() != "0");

        }

        static string DoAQuery()
        {
            string prompts = "0: Quit \n" +
                             "1: Who wrote <song name> \n" +
                             "2: What does <musician name> play \n" +
                             "3: What songs were written by <composer> \n" +
                             "4: Who plays in the <band name> \n" +
                             "5: Who's recorded <song name> \n" +
                             "6: What songs has the <band name> recorded \n" +
                             "7: Has the <band name> recorded <song name> \n";

            Console.WriteLine(prompts);

            Console.Write("Enter a command number: ");
            string cmd = Console.ReadLine();


            switch (cmd)
            {
                case "0" :
                    return cmd;

                case "1" :
                    Case1();
                    return cmd;

                case "2" :
                    Case2();
                    return cmd;

                case "3":
                    Case3();
                    return cmd;

                case "4":
                    Case4();
                    return cmd;

                case "5":
                    Case5();
                    return cmd;

                case "6":
                    Case6();
                    return cmd;

                case "7":
                    Case7();
                    return cmd;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("!!Command must be a number 0-7!!");
                    return "1";
            }
```

This is what it prints

```
    loaded 8 tunes
    0: Quit
    1: Who wrote <song name>
    2: What does <musician name> play
    3: What songs were written by <composer>
    4: Who plays in the <band name>
    5: Who's recorded <song name>
    6: What songs has the <band name> recorded
    7: Has the <band name> recorded <song name>

    Enter a command number: 0

    0: Quit
    1: Who wrote <song name>
    2: What does <musician name> play
    3: What songs were written by <composer>
    4: Who plays in the <band name>
    5: Who's recorded <song name>
    6: What songs has the <band name> recorded
    7: Has the <band name> recorded <song name>
    Enter a command number: 0
```

Basically I just want the input of a zero to quit the program immediately. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You invoke `DoAQuery()` twice per loop iteration. That's why it is invoked twice.

Comment: just to add to what zerkms said, remove the DoAQuery that come before the Console.WriteLine(); or store the result of it into a variable and check it in the while condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happening because you're invoking `DoAQuery()` twice in your code.

You could refactor it in this way:

```
string response;
do
{
    response = DoAQuery();
    Console.WriteLine();
} while (response != "0");
```

So you capture the user selection once then use it multiple times.